# Angular 8 GET request to C# API

Tags: c#, angular

I am building an app wherein I have two scenarios:

1. I pass in no variable (no sort) into the API url;
2. I pass in a variable (sort) into the API url.

How do I expose the variable from the JavaScript API call to the C# API.

**Angular**

```
  // pass in no value (default, when page is refreshed)

  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    http.get<Person[]>(baseUrl + 'person').subscribe(result => {
      this.persons = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }

 // when button is clicked (pass in through parameter)

 sort(order: string) {
     const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
     let params = new HttpParams();
     this.http.get<Person[]>(baseUrl + `person?sort=${order}`).subscribe(result => {
         this.persons = result;
     }, error => console.error(error));
 }
```

**C#**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class PersonController : ControllerBase
{
    static string address = "https://demo6957850.mockable.io/people";

    [HttpGet("{sort}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string sort)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: You can pass the default sort parameter when the sorting is not changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HttpParams to pass the sort variable into server API

```
const httpParams = order ? { params: new HttpParams().set('sort', order) } : {};
this.http.get<Person[]>(baseUrl + `person', httpParams)
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently your endpoint is specifying `sort` as a route parameter, which will be required to pass in when making a request. Since you want that parameter to be optional, you can simply remove that parameter from the route template and it will be treated as a query parameter:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string sort) 
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient()) 
    { 
        try { } 
    } 
}
```